# From date with time to date without time in PHP

Tags: php, string, date, date-format

I have to convert this string date `2016-09-26 00:00:00.000` to the `yyyy-mm-dd` format without other characters.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Simplest solution is: `$date = preg_replace("/\s{1}\d{2}:\d{2}\:\d{2}/",'',$datetime);`

Answer (score 11):

You can just use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class along with the `format()` method:

```
$d = new DateTime('2016-09-26 00:00:00.000');
echo $d->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$datetime = '2016-09-26 00:00:00.000';

$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2016-09-26 00:00:00.000'));
```

you will get the only date part in `'yyyy-mm-dd'` format.

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = strtotime('2016-09-26 00:00:00.000');
$test1 = date('Y-m-d h:i', $test);
$array1 = explode(' ', $var);
$date_temp = $array1[0];
```